# HTML show element if class not visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is this elaborate page I build with a lot of jQuery, hiding and showing elements, based on class.

To get an idea:

```
<p class='lookup'>You can lookup all the values.</p>
```

If the user can't do a lookup, I just do a

```
$('.lookup').hide() ;
```

in jQuery. It all works perfectly, all is fine.

Now I am adding only a simple remark in the HTML. However, the remark is different for when class 'lookup' is visible or not. (Basically a sort of if else.)

```
<p class='lookup'>Show me when class lookup is visible</p>
<p ????>Show me when class lookup is not visible</p>
```

Is there a really simple solution or hack  for this in html/css or even jQuery (but outside of the existing jQuery) that would SHOW a paragraph whenever `$('.lookup').hide() ;` is done and hides if a `$('.lookup').show() ;` is done?

I am just curious, I already work with an extra class 'noLookup' and added code to the existing jQuery, but it just feels like there should be a basic workaround/solution for this that I am just overlooking.

Comment: have you tried $(element).is(":visible");  or $(element).is(":hidden");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `style` attribute selector to check if the `.lookup` element is hidden:

```js
$("#chk").on("change", function() {
  var lookup = $('.lookup');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    lookup.show();
  } else {
    lookup.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.no-lookup {
  display: none;
}

.lookup[style*="display: none;"] ~ .no-lookup {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Toggle lookup</label>
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" checked />
<p class="lookup">You can look up!</p>
<p class="no-lookup">Sorry, you can't look up :(</p>
```

Comment: Ah, you changed your answer, this awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you:

```
$(function () {
  $(".lookup1, .lookup2").hide();

  $(".something1, .something2").bind("click", function () {
    $(".lookup1, .lookup2").hide();        

    if ($(this).attr("class") == "something1")
    {
      $(".lookup1").show();
    }
    else
    {
      $(".lookup2").show();
    }
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cEJtA/

Comment: Thank you. But his is way more complex than the simple class='noLookup' solution and also involves changing the original jQuery; not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the execution time which is default 400ms.
The second argument of the jQuery hide() function is the callback. So you can write it like this:

```
$('.lookup').hide(400, $('.otherElement').show());
```

Now it will run when .hide is done.

It works exactly the same for the show function.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Interesting., It's not much different from
`$('.lookup').hide();$('.noLookup').show();`
though, is it? Also involves changing the original jQuery. (I already did that, I guess it's the only solution. It just FEELS like there should be another, even simpler solution.)